# How to store the_title() values in array

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to store the_title() values into an array so i can print them index wise where i want.

```
<?php $popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'meta_key' => 
      'wpb_post_views_count' ,'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'post_type'=> 'idea'   
       ) );
       while ( $popularpost->have_posts()) : $popularpost->the_post();the_title();
       endwhile;  
?>
```

i tried one solution from stackoverflow but it can only store current post value in variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[the_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) function prints the title or returns as string.

Use it third parameter to retrieve value instead of directly printing it.

Append it to pre defined array.

Thats it!!!

> Parameters:
>
> $before (string) (Optional) Markup to prepend to the title. Default value: ''
>
> $after (string) (Optional) Markup to append to the title. Default value: ''
>
> $echo (bool) (Optional) Whether to echo or return the title. Default true for echo. Default value: true

```
<?php $popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'meta_key' =>
        'wpb_post_views_count' ,'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'post_type'=> 'idea'
) );
$titles = array();
while ( $popularpost->have_posts()) : $popularpost->the_post();
$titles[] = the_title('', '', FALSE); // set third parameter to FALSE.
endwhile;

var_dump($titles);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Post title store in array

```
<?php 
$popularpost = null;
$popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'meta_key' =>
        'wpb_post_views_count' ,'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'post_type'=> 'idea'
) );


if( $popularpost->have_posts() ) 
{
    $post_title_array = array();
    while ( $popularpost->have_posts()) : $popularpost->the_post();
        $post_title_array[] = get_the_title($post->ID);
    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query($popularpost);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($post_title_array);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php
 $popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'meta_key' => 
              'wpb_post_views_count' ,'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'post_type'=> 'idea'   
               ) );

           $postTitles = [];

               while ( $popularpost->have_posts()) : $popularpost->the_post();

                   $postTitles[] = get_the_title();

               endwhile; 

        print_r($postTitles);

    ?>
```